# Make activity shorter when swiped down like in Youtube in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am making a music player app. Like in YouTube, when the user swipes down on an activity then the activity must become smaller and must get to the bottom of the screen. How can I do that on Android Studio?

Comment: This is not trivial to answer. You may do some research in fragments and dialogs.

Comment: search for picture in picture mode

Comment: I didn't quite get you. Could you please explain?

Comment: This might help you
https://blog.iamsuleiman.com/android-o-tutorial-picture-in-picture-pip/

Comment: This is also a good link: https://www.zoftino.com/android-picture-in-picture-mode-example